# Rails Factory_Bot and reflect_on_association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

So im writing tests using RSpec + Factory_Bot_Rails. Im trying to test associations. Everything is working besides this:

I set up the sample data via:

```
let(:widget){ FactoryBot.create(:widget) }
```

But if I do something like:

```
widget.reflect_on_association(:widget_owner)
```

I receive an error:

```
undefined method `reflect_on_association' for #<Widget:0x007f9a4cdedb98>
```

This makes me think the factory w/let isn't actually creating the data? (Even though I see it being created in the database...). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know [ActiveRecord::Reflection::ClassMethods#reflect_on_association](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_association) is a class method, but `widget` is an instance, so `widget.class.reflect_on_association(:widget_owner)` should work.

Comment: Ah good point. Some examples I saw were referring to the instance for some reason. In that case....does it really make sense to write a test for this? Since aren't you just checking ActiveRecord at that point?

Answer (score 1):

For testing association, assuming widget has one widget_owner

```
expect(Widget.reflect_on_association(:widget_owner).macro).to eq :has_one
```